Movie about a lady's introduction to professional wrestling
I saw it, it's not a great movie, but I want to get the title for a discussion on movie plot development.   It came out maybe late 60s or early/mid 70s.   A promoter sees the lady beating up a guy who gets fresh with her at a restaurant or movie theater where she works.   She's introduced to "professional" wrestling, some of the people are nice, some are mean.   She has a bit of a deer in the headlights feeling to the whole thing but she seems physically capable of holding her own in the ring.
There's the typical villain in the movie, a muscular blond woman who can do upside-down situps off the ropes of the wrestling ring and in the middle of the movie she injures one of the friends of the heroin.   The climax of the movie (ofcourse), she faces this muscular blond in the ring and manages to win.   The way she wins isn't quite believable, the muscular lady jumps off the top rope and all she does is role out of the way and the muscular lady hits the mat.    I think she's latin/spanish and the movie is loosely based on a real person's experience in professional wrestling.
Some other tidbits, at one point she wrestles her boyfriend on their bed and wins - he doesn't like that and he leaves her.   And there's a line in the movie "Old wrestlers never die, they just fake away", and shortly after, one of the lady wrestlers leaves the business, marrying a trainer and she waves goodbye to everyone before driving off. 
Nobody famous was in the movie that I know of and I think it was a box office failure.
Thanks!!

Derp.   I really do feel stupid when I do this, but shortly after typing the details, I remembered her name was Rose or Rosa and the Mexican Spitfire, and that made googling the movie easy.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080427/?ref_=nv_sr_2
Below the Belt, 1980.  
